# GNOME Panel Completely Blank

Tags: gnome, kali-linux, gnome-panel

I had rebooted my laptop running Debian while it was in a perfectly fine running state. After the reboot, I log in again, and the top GNOME panel is completely blank. I only have one panel as I use Cairo Dock in the place of the bottom panel. 
When I look at dconf, the applets are still there, but the panel doesn't show it.

Now, I can make a second panel, I can delete the top one and recreate it. If I do that, I can re-add my applets just fine, but the User Menu and the Custom Menu Labels applets cause it to freeze up to where the existing applets still show and work fine, but applets that are added afterwards do not show nor do they function.

Even after a reboot, the applets that were already there just disappear and it's blank and still frozen. I believe it may have been a package I installed on the same day and have pasted a link to my `apt` and `dpkg` logs.

I looked everywhere online and could not find someone with a similar issue. Any help at all will be much appreciated. Also, it's specific to this user. Other users work fine.

If I delete the dconf 'user' file and reboot, there are no problems at all. But if I reboot again, then its back to the same issue. I'm utterly lost as to what to do.

Dpkg Log: http://pastebin.com/BirG4CGe

APT Log: http://pastebin.com/9RVfdEpZ

System Info: Linux kali 3.7-trunk-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.7.2-0+kali5 x86_64 GNU/Linux